# where can i download Facebook's source code transformer HipHop for PHP

Tags: php, facebook, hiphop

Where can I download HipHop for PHP?

Comment: This is a real question folks. "HipHop programmatically transforms your PHP source code into highly optimized C++ and then uses g++ to compile it."

Comment: While a valid question indeed, am I the only one who gets a headache even just from the thought that this actually exists?

Comment: @Esko: Because it's for php? Or do you dislike automated code generation/transformation in general? (Just so we know in which direction this rant will lead ;-))

Comment: @Esko, I don't get a headache, but a slightly perturbed look on my face when I read the *name*. What a *damn* stupid name. :) The concept, though, sounds interesting to me.

Comment: Read through the links given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055875/hiphop-php-was-hyper-php-by-facebook/2183413#2183413 and then reconsider if you really need HipHop or if APC or memcached is more suitable to your need.

Comment: @VolkerK: I think the name is awful, I think that using PHP as a source is an odd point to even start with *(I don't dislike PHP itself by the way even though I'm not a fan of it)* and I do dislike any form of code generation in general with some really specific exceptions. Oh and the fact that it's done by Facebook doesn't really add points to my trust on this thing even working properly, ref. FB API. So basically there's nothing in it that would make me feel even slightly positive about it.

Comment: This is a very real question with good answers below. The original announcement of HipHop stated that it would be made available on the evening of Feb 2nd. However, as jeroen.vangoey's answer explains, this didn't quite happen.

This question should absolutely not be closed.

Comment: Voting to reopen the question. HipHop can be downloaded at http://wiki.github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/

Answer (score 6):

See [this message](http://groups.google.com/group/hiphop-php-dev/msg/91aa73adcbf1c4a0) on the mailing list:

> On Feb 5, 12:00 pm, Dan  wrote:
>
> > Hey, Just wondering, I'm sure you've been asked a lot already... but when 
> >     is the Github project going to be opened?
>
> We're in the process of opening the list and approving members to the 
>   group. Code will follow soon after any recent cherges have been merged 
>   to the branch and we're sure that anything Facebook specific is 
>   removed.
>
> Scott MacVicar

[Scott MacVicar](http://www.macvicar.net/blog/2009/12/funemployment-part-3-back-to-work.html) is the Open Source Developer Advocate at Facebook. The github project they are referring to will be located at http://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether it has been released yet, but if there is a download, you will find it  here: 
[**HipHop for PHP: Move Fast**](http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=358)

If the official blog is not offering a download, no one else will either.

Answer (score 1):

It's not available yet. It should be available later this week.

You can read more about that at: http://groups.google.com/group/hiphop-php-dev/browse_thread/thread/c63edd95f6cc5cfa

It will be up on GitHub when it's released.